# Extract changes from diff file to current branch

Tags: git

I have a file that I generated by using:

> ~ git diff --color > diff.file

And I now want to bring that onto my current branch.

I tried using:

> ~ git apply diff.file

Although that responds with fatal: unrecognized input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **--color** flag makes diff.file into a binary file which is unable to be read when using ***git apply***

Removing the --color flag resulted in a file that was easily readable for git apply.