# git patches cause error unrecognized input

Tags: git, osx-mavericks

I'm running Mac OSX 10.9.4 (Mavericks) and have git version 2.8.2. I've tested this with a completely new repo.  Here's example.

```
mkdir gitest
cd gitest
git init
echo "monkeyface" > monkey.txt
git commit -m "first commit"
echo "monkeyface farted" > monkeyfart.txt
git add .
git diff HEAD > new.patch
rm monkeyfart.txt
git reset --hard HEAD
git apply new.patch --check
>fatal: unrecognized input
```

Any ideas what is causing this?  Could it be anything in my .gitconfig file?

```
[user]
    name = myusername
    email = myemail@mail.com
[color]
  ui = always
[alias]
  st = status -sb -uall
  lg = log --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --graph
  undocommit = reset --soft HEAD^
  undopush = push -f origin HEAD^:master
[core]
    editor = vim
    excludesfile = ~/.gitignore_global
    pager = less -r
[commit]
  template = ~/.gitmessage.txt
[filter "media"]
    clean = git-media-clean %f
    smudge = git-media-smudge %f
```

UPDATE:

While the answer linked below offers some idea on what the problem might have been, my issue was specifically hidden in my configuration since no color argument was being passed into the command.   This answer is relevant but my question and answer might be helpful to others who may experience a similar issue.

[Extract changes from diff file to current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22385091/extract-changes-from-diff-file-to-current-branch)

Comment: What did you expect by `git commit -i "first commit"` here? Isn't it `-m`?

Comment: You're correct, that was a typo, fixing now thanks.

Comment: No, not me. I never downvote others. If I want to, I just do nothing.

Comment: I think `git diff HEAD` outputs nothing and new.patch is actually empty.

Comment: `$ cat new.patch 
   diff --git a/monkeyfart.txt b/monkeyfart.txt
   new file mode 100644
   index 0000000..37b2f7e
   --- /dev/null
+++ b/monkeyfart.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+monkeyface farted`

Comment: Well, I tried your example but got no error. In the end, I got untracked monkeyfart.txt and new.patch in the work tree.

Comment: That's the point.  There's no reason I can tell why this should fail.  I'm wondering if it my be something in my gitconfig.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract changes from diff file to current branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22385091/extract-changes-from-diff-file-to-current-branch)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### Updated

First thing is to ignore color when creating the patch

```
git diff --no-color > my_patch.patch
```

You might have a file which was not encoded to UTF-8. To fix that on *nix systems (MacOS, Linux etc.)

```
iconv -f ascii -t utf-8 fix.patch -o fix_utf8.patch
```

For windows you can try:

```
Get-Content .\fix.patch | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 fix_utf8.patch
```

If your file may already have color codes in it you can try:

```
git apply --reject --whitespace myfile.patch
```

Passing in no-color param also
git diff HEAD --color=never > fix.patch

And now check returns no error message.

```
git apply fix.patch --check
```

Changing my .gitconfig file from

```
[color]
    ui = always
```

change to always

```
[color]
    ui = auto
```

Fixed my problem so I do not have to pass color option when diffing to patch file.

UPDATE:  Based on saurabheights answer, you don't even need to `brew link gnu-sed`, you can do this with pearl. This will removed color characters from the bad patch file as well. There are probably many ways to do this.

```
perl -pe 's/\x1b.*?[mGKH]//g' bad.patch > good.patch
```

Comment: Thanks. fixing the encoding worked for me.

Answer (score 55):

There is format problem in patch file. To fixthe path file:

1. Open your patch file in notepad++ then enter these two menus:

   ```
   Encoding/Convert to UTF-8
   Edit/EOL conversion/Unix (LF)
   ```
2. Run:

   ```
   git apply --reject --whitespace=fix your_patch.patch
   ```

Comment: I know this is late, but this helped out immensely on some code that I would have lost.

Comment: like the `--whitespace=fix` switch but part 1 of your answer is windows os specific.

Comment: For me, just converting diff file to UTF-8 did the job

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed. I had created the patch by redirecting the output of a "git stash show" to a file in Windows.

Comment: A person like you have a special place in heaven. I wish SO has a way to "buy a coffee"

Answer (score 13):

We tried debugging this for a few hours. What finally worked was this:

1. Opened patch file with an editor like `VS Code`
2. Changed encoding to `UTF-8`
3. Changed line endings from `CRLF` to `LF`
4. Saved the new file
5. `git apply myPatch.patch` worked

Comment: what OS were you using?

Comment: Thanks this works, remember to save with encoding using utf8.

Comment: It works for me, windows so

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, For Visual Studio:

1. Open the file
2. From Menu: File -> Save **filename** As...
3. Select 'Save with Encoding...'

[image: Save with Encoding]

4. Select the following:

   - Encoding: UTF-8 with/without signature
   - Line endings: Unix (LF)

[image: Encoding Options]

5. Save the file
6. Run `git apply MyPatch.patch` again

Comment: does this work on windows if you run from cmd `Get-Content .\fix.patch | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 fix_utf8.patch` then try to apply the ut8 file?

Comment: This work for me, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For those who already have a patch with color codes, try this:-

On **Ubuntu**:-

```
cat incorrect.patch | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mGK]//g" > correct.patch
```

On **Mac**, install gsed using:-

```
brew link gnu-sed
```

and to generate correct patch file:-

```
cat incorrect.patch | gsed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mGK]//g" > correct.patch
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick solution in Windows:

1. Open notepad
2. Copy your `git diff` content to blank document in Notepad
3. Save as a new file
4. `git apply` the file

It's important to copy content, not just to open the diff file in notepad.

Comment: omg i love you. maybe not the most elegant solution, but works perfectly fine for me 

Comment: Used this method in Windows, and it worked! Thank you.